# ERROR 1064 в MySQL Workbench при создании таблицы

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Цель была: продолжить работу над проектом на языке Java, в котором используется база данных. 
Ход действий:
1. Установка MySQL Community Server и IntellJ IDEA. 
2. Создание в MySQL Workbench тестовой схемы и создание там тестовой таблицы. Все прошло успешно. 
3. Настройка IDE с БД. 
 
4. Импорт дампа БД в MySQL Workbench. 
5. Импорт проекта на Java в IDE. 
6. Компиляция проекта и запуск, проверка работы приложения с БД. Прошло успешно. 
7. Попытка создать новую таблицу рядом с уже существующими, получение ошибки: 

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
    CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
    );

ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 2
SQL Statement:
    CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
    )


8. Создание новой тестовой схемы, не касающейся проекта, попытка создать там тестовую таблицу. Также ошибка та же.

В чем может быть проблема? Операции просмотра записей в таблицах, добавление новой записи происходят без проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По факту всё написано в ответе MySQL.

У Вас ошибка в синтаксисе.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ')' at line 2

Для наглядности я решил протестировать Ваш запрос и воспроизвести ошибку...и да!..она абсолютно аналогична Вашей.

В ошибке говорится что, что-то не так у вас возле закрывающей скобочки и что Вам нужно сверить Ваш запрос с документацией.

Вопрос: Что же может там быть?

Идём в документацию и смотрим синтаксис запроса CREATE:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
column_name1 data_type(size),
column_name2 data_type(size),
column_name3 data_type(size),
....
);
```

Из него видно что MySQL ожидает, что между скобками будет описание полей таблицы, которых нет и это он считает ошибкой.

Попробуем добавить поле:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`new_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

И всё отлично работает!

**Вам нужно добавить описание полей в запрос.**

**Ваш запрос неверный.**

По поводу создания схемы могу сказать только одно:

Дайте Ваш запрос и сообщение об ошибке!

Я подозреваю, что ответ находится именно в них!

**Учитесь читать сообщения об ошибках!** Как правило они отражают суть проблемы.

Comment: По каким-то причинам спряталась область, в которой создаются колонки (ну, если использовать графический интерфейс), и я забыл об этом.. Если можно, еще вопрос, возник. Не знаете как перезапустить процесс mysqld.exe? Если его убить вручную, а потом пытаться запустить, появляется консоль, потом быстро закрывается и процесс не запускается. Если перезагрузить компьютер, процесс запускается сам и все нормально. Но хочется как-то упростить это.

Comment: @Rob, если работаете под Windows, зайдите в диспетчер задач, перейдите на вкладку службы, там найдите MySQL и перезапустите. Под Linux как правило что-то вроде `service mysqld restart`  в консоли (конкретный синтаксис зависит от дистрибутива)

Comment: @Rob, в Java-коде у Вас не будет графического интерфейса. Выучите синтаксис и потренируйтесь в Workbench'e. Поверьте с практикой это не долго и запоминается на всю жизнь.

Comment: @Rob, в Workbench'е тоже можно перезапустить MySQL-сервер. Вкладка Server на главное панели сверху и там пункт Startup/Shutdown